# Weblogic 14 Compatibility with Adopt Open Jdk 11

Tags: weblogic, adoptopenjdk

as Oracle moving JDK to licensed from >1.8. will weblogic 14 servers supports Adopt Open JDK?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The answer is clearly no. WebLogic Server 14c is only supported by Oracle with Oracle Jdk (8 or 11)